# C++, assignment of non-pointer type to a member pointer of template class

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, constructor, member

While looking for a example of binary tree implementation, I've noticed something strange in the code provided [here](https://gist.github.com/mgechev/5911348). In *Node* structure's constructor a non-pointer type variable is assigned to a pointer type.

It compiles just fine (I'm using GCC 5.3.0). And what made me really confused is that compilation depends on other constructor's parameter, *val*.

It have no effect in class methods, only in constructors:

```
template <typename T>
class Test {
    Test* testPtr;

    void testMethod(T t, Test<T> notAPointer) { // OK
        this->testPtr = notAPointer;
    }

    void testMethod(Test<T> notAPointer) {      // OK
        this->testPtr = notAPointer;
    }

    Test(T t, Test<T> notAPointer) {            // OK
        this->testPtr = notAPointer;
    }

    Test(Test<T> notAPointer) {                 // compilation error
        this->testPtr = notAPointer;
    }
};
```

The compilation error I'm getting is:

> invalid constructor; you probably meant ‘Test (const Test&)’

Why is that happening? Where in the standard is this behaviour described?

Comment: I think it's a typo. It compiles fine because the constructor in question is not called.

Comment: Which constructor is called when constructing the `notAPointer` parameter?

Comment: The issue with your constructor has absolutely nothing to do with pointer assignment or any accompanying issues. You will get the same error with empty constructor body. Copy constructor cannot receive its parameter by value - that's all there is to it and that is what your compiler is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last constructor is a [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor). It's forbidden to have a copy constructor that passes its parameter by value, as otherwise you'd end up with infinite recursion.

The error you're getting is similar to

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(Foo);
};
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5dcf23138f7898d)

More precisely, according to the standard:

**12.8/2 Copying and moving class objects [class.copy]**

> A non-template constructor for class `X` is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments (8.3.6). [ Example: `X::X(const X&)` and `X::X(X&,int=1)` are copy constructors.

The others constructors/member functions seem ok because they are not instantiated, and the code is syntactically correct (in theory, `Test<T>` may have a conversion operator to `T*` for some specialization, and the compiler cannot check that before instantiation). However the copy constructor has to have a definite form, which is being enforced by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

All of your examples are invalid. You will get a compiler error when you try to **instantiate** any method:

```
template <typename T>
struct Test {
    Test* testPtr;

    void testMethod(Test<T> notAPointer) {
        this->testPtr = notAPointer;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test<int> t1, t2;
    t1.testMethod(t2); // This line will cause the error.

    return 0;
}
```

> prog.cpp: In instantiation of 'void Test::testMethod(Test) [with
>   T = int]': prog.cpp:16:18:   required from here prog.cpp:9:23: error:
>   cannot convert 'Test' to 'Test*' in assignment
>            this->testPtr = notAPointer;
>                          ^